# Read and search buffer from a table text file from user input and display correct table location in C

Tags: arrays, c, search, text, buffer

I have a table.txt file:

```
class #1
Sect1: cat
Sect2: dog
Sect3: mouse
Sect4: bird
Sect5: squirrel

class#2
Sect1: shark
Sect2: octopus
Sect3: tuna
Sect4: eel
Sect5: dolphin
```

I am able to read the text file and place its contents into a buffer. I prompt the user to enter an animal and the program will search the table and output the location of animal in the table. Example below:

```
Enter animal to search for: mouse
The animal mouse is located at Class #1 in Sect#3
```

I am trying to find the best method to do the search but I am unsure. Thanks y'all for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    FILE* infile;
    char* buffer;
    long numbytes;
    char animal[10];
    char class[10];
    char sect[10];

    infile = fopen("table.txt", "r");

    if (NULL == infile) {
        printf("file can't be opened \n");
    }

    /* Get the number of bytes */
    fseek(infile, 0L, SEEK_END);
    numbytes = ftell(infile);

    /* reset the file position indicator to
    the beginning of the file */
    fseek(infile, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    /* grab sufficient memory for the
    buffer to hold the text */
    buffer = (char*)calloc(numbytes, sizeof(char));

    /* memory error */
    if (buffer == NULL)
        return 1;

    /* copy all the text into the buffer */
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), numbytes, infile);
    fclose(infile);

    printf("Enter animal to search: ");
    scanf("%s", animal);

    //to do animal search
    
    printf("\nThe aninmal %s is located in %s and %s", animal, class, sect);

    /* free the memory we used for the buffer */
    free(buffer);

    // Closing the file
    fclose(infile);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried scanning each line item into an array or using a struct to organize it but not totally sure what the best method is. Am I constructing the buffer appropriately to search or do I need to parse it afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Simply search *backwards* through the buffer to find the animal:

```
char *cp = buffer + numbytes - strlen(animal);
while( cp > buffer && strncmp( cp, animal, strlen( animal ) ) // non-zero = mismatch
    cp--;

// cp now points to the first letter of the animal. No duplicates, I hope.
if( cp == buffer )
    // not found... exit

// Use similar idea to search _backwards_ to find the preceding "Sect?" value
// and then again to find the "Class?" value...
// Use one variable to store the 'section' info, and one for the 'class'
```

You could go to the effort of *parsing* the file, breaking things into a hierarchy of pointers and null-terminated strings... Will the program "live" for more than just a single search?

(Of course, `strstr()` could be used to find the animal if the buffer were *null terminated*, and then reverse searching for local 'section' and 'class' carried-out. There are lots of ways to do this!)

In fact, it would be advantageous to allocate one extra byte at the end of the buffer, regardless:

```
char *buffer = calloc( numbytes + 1, sizeof *buffer );
```

Notice that `buffer` is declared & defined when it is first used. You could do this with the other variables, too.

---

**Problems:**

1. Don't continue execution if `fopen()` fails.

2. Don't call `fclose()` twice on the same FILE pointer.

3. Don't cast the return pointer from `calloc()`.

4. `scanf("%s", animal);` ==> `scanf("%9s", animal);`

5. Why scrimp on memory? 10 bytes for a string is paltry!

---

**Suggestion:**

Encapsulate all the code that loads the buffer into a function. Pass the filename and receive back a pointer to the (null terminated) buffer (that must be `free()`'d. Not only does that "unclutter" `main()`, but you might be able to use the same "file loading" code in other projects.

Comment: Yes, I plan to construct it where the program is in a while loop until the user inputs a command to end the search. Will this be the proper way to null terminate my buffer: buffer[sizeof(buffer)-1] = '\0';

Comment: `buffer` is a pointer. `sizeof` will be the size of a pointer (4 bytes? 8 bytes?)... If you `calloc()` one extra byte that is not used, the last byte will be '\0' already.

Answer (score 0):

In reviewing what your project is attempting to do, I took your code and did a bit of refactoring and introduced a new item you may or may not be familiar with, and that is a structure.  The characteristics of each animal (name, class, section) seemed to fit into the usage of a structure array such that you might read and store the animals you have there.  With that, here is a refactored version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct animal
{
    char aname[30];
    char cls[20];
    char section[10];
} animal;

int main()
{
    animal a[20];
    char genus[20];
    char cl[10];
    char buffer[40];
    char text[40];
    int count = 0;
    int found = 0;

    FILE* infile;

    infile = fopen("table.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(buffer, 40, infile) != NULL)
    {
        int word_length = strlen(buffer);

        if (word_length < 2)                    /* Handle skipping a blank line */
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (buffer[word_length - 1] == '\n')    /* Handle the newline character */
        {
            buffer[word_length - 1] = '\0';
        }
        strcpy(text, buffer);

        if (strstr(text, "Class"))              /* Check to see if this line denotes a start of a class group */
        {
            strcpy(cl, text);                   /* Store class name value to be placed into the animal structure array */
        }
        else
        {
            char * sect = strtok(text, " : ");  /* Acquire the section substring from the text string */
            strcpy(a[count].cls, cl);
            strcpy(a[count].section, sect);
            char * name = strtok(NULL, " : ");  /* Acquire the animal's name from the text string */
            strcpy(a[count].aname, name);
            count++;
        }
    }
    fclose(infile);

    while (1)                                   /* Now prompt the user to enter in an animal name */
    {
        printf("Enter animal to search or type \"quit\" to end the search: ");

        if(scanf("%s", genus) < 1)              /* scanf safeguard */
        {
            printf("Incorrect entry - please try again\n");
        }

        if (strcmp(genus, "quit") == 0)         /* Done with entries - end the program */
        {
            break;
        }

        found = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(a[i].aname, genus) == 0)
            {
                printf("The aninmal %s is located in %s and %s \n", a[i].aname, a[i].cls, a[i].section);
                found = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (found == 0)
        {
            printf("Sorry, the animal requested was not found in the database - please try again\n");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here are some of the highlights.

- Since there will be various tests on character arrays (strings) the "string.h" file is included for access to string functionality.
- An animal data structure is defined that will be able to contain the three basic elements you have noted for each animal (its name, its class, and its section).
- An animal structure array is defined to contain the data elements for each animal defined in the text file - an arbitrary size of twenty was chosen, but this could be much larger to accommodate whatever number of animals will be stored.
- As the text file is read, the data record read will determine if a new class group has been reached or if an actual animal record is being read.
- If a class designation is found, that class is saved for subsequent storage for each animal read until a new class designation record is read.
- For each animal record read, its name, class, and section information is placed into a data structure array element.
- Once all of the animal data has been read from the file, then a "while" loop is used to allow for the user to enter in an animal name.
- For each animal found, its class, section, and name is listed, until the user enters the literal "quit" which ends the program execution.

Following is a sample of the output at the terminal utilizing the your data file.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Animals/bin/Release$ ./Animals 
Enter animal to search or type "quit" to end the search: mouse
The aninmal mouse is located in Class #1 and Sect3 
Enter animal to search or type "quit" to end the search: dog
The aninmal dog is located in Class #1 and Sect2 
Enter animal to search or type "quit" to end the search: emu
Sorry, the animal requested was not found in the database - please try again
Enter animal to search or type "quit" to end the search: quit
```

If structures are a new concept to you, you may want to try a different approach, or possibly this might be the time to investigate the usage of structures.  Anyway, give this a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: I've made my list bigger and included a mix of animals. I'm getting a stack error when I type quit. Should I resize the array. ```Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted.
```